# Quickblox Android SDK Push Notification error - Unable to deliver notification 11897158, received error 401 (Unauthorized, check your App auth_key.)

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

After Chat module integration in my `APP` , I am now trying to integrate the `Push Notifications/Messsage` module. After many trial and errors and reading through many similar issues on web too, I am unable to resolve the error -

> Unable to deliver notification 11897158, received error 401
>   (Unauthorized, check your App auth_key.)"}]}

I am attaching the error log. I have followed all the steps mentioned on the page:

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android.

```
{"notification":{"registration_ids":["APA91bGo_dbGLikYmsLI_iNUAAqjShKNjAokWgCINioAhit4tKdntaA0akZePAWnBXV5ERSnW6Yr9mlYPeta2VUNDILPpYWh-vxijIGQav_o5icwW9MWUbQ","APA91bE_ShWzcXBYIxQuHJV95VWm2M7IqyjdoT8EacOdtFj3EiIwwSrm4lAgZ06OMOmvD4aADNKHEcb77ygClpurpmIZ81QDTMD8pENCDqcjBJfNQbR4Zu8"],"delay_while_idle":false,"data":{"message":"You have a new message dated today","type":"welcome message","collapse_key":"event5781307"},"time_to_live":86400},"log":[{"device_token":null,"created_at":"2016-02-29T16:18:41Z","delivered_at":null,"failed_at":"2016-02-29T16:18:43Z","error_code":401,"error_description":"Unable to deliver notification 11897158, received error 401 (Unauthorized, check your App auth_key.)"}]}
```